# How to be able to concatenate the values of a column with the name of the other columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

How to be able to concatenate the values of a column called "ITEM" with the name of the other columns, thus creating new columns.

If I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ITEM': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
    'Variable1': [1,1,2],
    'Variable2': [2,1,3],
    'Variable3':[3,2,4]

})
df
```

I need to transform this dataframe:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxdfD.png)

on that dataframe:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y55IH.png)

Comment: please show what you tried. you could either use pandas functions (e.g [concat/join/etc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/merging.html)) or write two for-loops to iterate over the columns and the index.

Comment: Why are you posting pictures of data, just post the actual data and format it as code

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ITEM': ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'],
    'Variable1': [1,1,2],
    'Variable2': [2,1,3],
    'Variable3':[3,2,4]

})

df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='ITEM',value_vars=['Variable1','Variable2','Variable3'])
df['title'] = df['variable']+'_'+df['ITEM']
df = df[['title','value']].T
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
```